# How can a server distinguish between a user using TBB and one that only use Tor as proxy?

Tags: python

I am currently scraping some websites(legitimately), using urllib2 on python with socksipy for Tor. I have changed the header fields to be identical to TBB. However, some websites seem to detect me as a spider/scraper. How are they able to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely these sites sets cookie and use JavaScript which urllib does not execute.

Use a real browser (TBB) with [WebDriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html).